# asp do while not when data not found for requested.form values and bold in last row

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a access query as below :

```
select column_date, sum(qty1), sum(qty2), sum(qty3) from table1
where column_date = [enter date]
group by column_date
union all
select 'Total' as column_date, sum(qty1), sum(qty2), sum(qty3) from table1
where column_date = [enter date]
```

Now I have asp code as below :

```
<%
Dim enterdate = Request.Form("enterdate")
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "odbcdatasourcename"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="abovequery '" & enterdate & "' "
rs.Open sql, conn
%>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<%If rs.EOF then
Response.write ("<center>" & "<b>" & "There is no records for 
the selected dates" & "</b>" & "</center>")%>
<%Else%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do while not rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
<td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
 rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop%>
<%End if%>
<%rs.close
conn.close%>
```

As you can see I have written it should display message "There is no records for the selected dates" when there is no data for the selected date. 
But it still displays only last row with "Total" every time there is no record i.e. second query with blank values.  Is it possible to fix it?

And I want to make "bold" last row i.e. Total row when there is record in database for selected date. Is it possible too here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two queries and should run them as such, first the query to get the data and then the query to get the total. The query as it stands will always return one row with Total as the date.

This is true even when the table is completely empty. You can check this by creating a table with one column called ID and no rows.

```
SELECT ID,ID As ASum
FROM EmptyTable
UNION
SELECT "Total" As ID, Sum(ID)
FROM EmptyTable
```

It will return one row.

Comment: Thanks Remou...I understood...but is there any work around for this?
 is it possible to create column total with asp code then instead of using query?

Comment: Just run two queries and use GetRows ( http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getrows.asp ) or GetString ( http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getstring.asp ) to store the values. This will sort out your bold problem and allow you to get in and out of MS Access very fast, always a good idea for web + Access.

Comment: By two queries, I mean the query to get the data and the queru to get the totals. Do not use union to add total to results.

Comment: Exactly, i used the same code here (http://www.codefixer.com/articles/getrows.htm). now it displays all rows in my page but still i'm not sure how I can make just last row bold? i cannot give exact row and column reference because each time the number of rows might change

Comment: Create two queries. Loop through the data or use get rows to create a table. Then write the total row. <%Data Loop%><%Bold Total%>